# Ember-Simple-Auth: Overloading sessionAuthenticationSucceeded

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I am currently trying to override `sessionAuthenticationSucceeded` in the `Ember.SimpleAuth.ApplicationRouteMixin` class, so that I can transition into my `routeAfterAuthentication` with a model passed in.

Basically `this.transitionTo(Configuration.routeAfterAuthentication, model);`, but even after doing `Ember.SimpleAuth.ApplicationRouteMixin.reopen()` my override of the function is never called. So am I going about this all wrong? Can Mixins not be reopened in this fashion? Or should I be passing the model to the `routeAfterAuthentication` transition in a different fashion.

EDIT: Stupid reputation limits, was gonna answer this myself but apparently have to wait 8 hours, so here is that answer for now:

Well, not entirely sure if this is the correct way to do this, but it works. I was looking through this example: [custom-server](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/examples/9-custom.html) and I wound up doing this to accomplish what I wanted.

```
var applicationRoute = container.lookup('route:application');
var session = container.lookup('ember-simple-auth-session:main');
var store = container.lookup('store:main');

session.on('sessionAuthenticationSucceeded', function() {
    var user = store.find('user', session.get('user_id'));
    container.lookup('controller:application').set('content', user)
    applicationRoute.transitionTo('profile.resume', user);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to simply define the `sessionAuthenticationSucceeded` on the application route instead of reopening the mixins:

```
/// routes/application.js
import ApplicationRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin, {
  actions: {
    sessionAuthenticationSucceeded: function() {
      …
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I should have came back and edited this, but I found a solution based on one of your examples, which I shall add as an answer below.

Comment: Yeah, but that solution is meant to be used if you're not using the mixins. If you're using the mixins the solution below is unnecessarily complex.

Comment: That makes sense, I did notice that with my current solution the transitionTo first starts within the RouteMixin and then is aborted and redone within the session.on. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Well, not entirely sure if this is the correct way to do this, but it works. I was looking through this example: [custom-server](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/examples/9-custom.html) and I wound up doing this to accomplish what I wanted.

```
var applicationRoute = container.lookup('route:application');
var session = container.lookup('ember-simple-auth-session:main');
var store = container.lookup('store:main');

    session.on('sessionAuthenticationSucceeded', function() {
        var user = store.find('user', session.get('user_id'));
        container.lookup('controller:application').set('content', user)
        applicationRoute.transitionTo('profile.resume', user);
    });
```